KeyCloak Session Cookies not set by identity provider
We have two KeyCloaks, let's call them Home and Remote.
When a client, like an app, wants to authenticate to Remote via Home we do the Standard Authentication Flow and add the kc_idp_hint. And that works and we are authenticated with Remote.
But on the remote URL, let's say remote.kc.com are no session cookies placed.
Where do we have to change the appropriate settings so that these session cookies are there  for the next Login?
When you natively authenticate via Remote the cookies are there, but not when you go through Home with the idp hint.

Are you using iframes? Your browser may block the cookies. Show us the network request/responses for an example authentication.
